# Instant cannot be serialized to appropriate format even with jackson-datatype-jsr310

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

Adding the following dependencies:

```
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.8.9")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.8.9")
compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.9")
```

I am now able to deserialize the following JSON with Instant:

```
{
    "timestamp": {{$timestamp}}
}
```

to the following object:

```
Transaction(timestamp=2017-07-02T10:58:18Z)
```

with the following class declaration

```
data class Transaction(@NotNull val timestamp: Instant)
```

However, when immediately serializing afterwards, I get the following:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1498992172
}
```

I am using **Spring Boot** with **Kotlin**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the [feature WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features#datatype-specific-serialization):

This can be achieved by adding the following in your application.yml file:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
```